# Am I using my Service properly with my Entities and Mappers. Is my business logic correct?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

In my application there are Customers and Couriers. A Customer can send a Delivery Request to a Courier only if that Courier is currently online and both users are from the same location.

When a Customer wants to send a Delivery Request to a Courier my `DeliveryRequest` service has a `sendDeliveryRequest(Request request)` method which is called from a `Controller`.

```
public function sendDeliveryRequest(Request $request) {

    $customer = $this->recognitionService->getUser();

    $courier = $this->entityFactory->build('Courier');
    $courier->setId( $request->post('courierId') );
    $courierMapper = $this->mapperFactory->build('Courier');
    $courierMapper->fetch($courier);

    $deliveryRequest = $this->entityFactory->build('DeliveryRequest');

    $someRequestedItems = array();
    $deliveryRequest->sendRequest($customer, $courier, $someRequestedItems);

}
```

So far in my `sendRequest(Customer $customer, Courier $courier, Array $items)` method I have:

```
public function sendRequest(Customer $customer, Courier $courier, Array $items) {

    // Check if the couriers account is active
    if( !$courier->isActive() ) {
        return 'courier not active';
    }
    // Check if the courier is online
    if( !$courier->isOnline() ) {
        return 'courier not online';
    }
    // Check the status of the customers location, active/inactive
    if( !$customer->getLocation()->isActive() ) {
        return 'customers location disabled';
    }
    // Check if the customer and the courier live in the same location
    if( !$customer->sameLocationAs($courier) ) {
        return 'customer and courier in different locations';
    }
    // More checks

}
```

To me so far it looks ok and runs well but I am not 100% sure if I am doing the business logic correctly, especially the `!$customer->sameLocationAs($courier)`.

That method uses the supplied `$courier` object to get that Couriers location(which is an object with an `id`) and compares it to the Customers location to check if they are in the same location. It works perfectly but I am unsure if that is the best way to accomplish checking if both users are from the same location or not. Is that valid **business logic?**

Also, the items in the `$deliveryRequest`, their data (`id`, `quantity`) will be in the `$request` object passed from the `Controller` so I will create each `Item` in the `Service` and put them in an array and pass the array with the `$customer` and `$courier` to the `sendRequest()` method. That means I have to do the checks (check if entered quantity is not more than database value of quantity etc) within that method, **is that the right way or is it bad?**

Am I doing my checks/validation correctly and in the correct place/layer in my application?

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, I would say your method 'sameLocationAs' is valid. The other possibility would have been to create a Util class that has static methods and which can provide services between classes.

This is the job of the model to check if the items are valid (not the controller), so you have two possibilities :

1. like you want to do
2. when you create the Item object, you can check the validity of the object in the item class or using observer Design pattern. (difficult and no need for that, interesting if you want to save automatically objects)
3. use a validation class that would do the job (it would be nice too)

It would be good if the code your service code concerns the service interests only.

But what you did is correct I would say and valid, you should only go a little bit further